# Apache FilesMatch : How to only match assets with a timestamp appended

Tags: apache2, httpd.conf, regex

I just wrote and answered a question regarding what apache FilesMatch recognizes as the filename; see [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531300/apache-filesmatch-regexp-can-it-match-by-the-cahce-buster-10-digit-rails-genera) for more on that, but the skinny is that apache does not recognize anything after the file extension, which includes the (rails appended) timestamp, on an asset as part of the filename.

That kind of sucks because we have assets that, for one reason or another, are not timestamped for cache-busting purposes, so a blanket match like this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|js|css)$">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "now plus 1 year"
</FilesMatch>
```

Is going to match both assets that are eligible for cache busting as well as those that are not. For those that are not, well, this can be bad.

So, can anybody tell me how to match assets only if they have a \?\d{10} following the filename?

Answer (score 1):

I found a hack that is not ideal, but given the limitations, will work. Check out these two sites for the solution:

- http://www.stephensykes.com/blog_perm.html?157
- http://bibwild.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/browser-caching-of-rails-assets-for-real/

Comment: rails 3.1 asset pipeline will also take care of this, by naming the files better.